# SQL Select statement MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below

```
Code    Thickness
TPLM        4
TP          4
TP          8
TP          12
TP          19
TPLM        8
TPLM        12
TPLM        19
```

The result I need when pass in TPLM 8.5 to select the result.  What is the query supposed to do with that value?

```
ProcessCode    Thickness
 TPLM            12
```

If the table only maintain the thickness until 19, when I pass in TPLM 30, I need the result is TPLM 19.  what is the query supposed to do with that value?

```
 ProcessCode    Thickness
 TPLM            19
```

Comment: How come you want that result?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements a bit?

Comment: The thickness in the table all in int.  But when in the selection, there can be decimal point for the thickness pass in to select the record.  I can't maintain all the thickness in the table because there is a lot of different thickness, eg 8.5, 8.6, 9.35 and so on.

Comment: You should edit your question with the additional information.  So you want the next value up from the value passed in?

Comment: The question that you should answer through editing your post is: "When *passing* a value of 8.5 to the query, what is the query supposed to do with that value?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM mytable
WHERE Code = 'TPLM' AND Thickness >= 8.5
ORDER BY Thickness
```

The query picks the first `TPLM` record equal to or exceeding `8.5` thickness value.

[**Demo by @Andy**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58aa24/7)

You can handle the edge case, where a value bigger than the maximum thickness value is selected, using:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM mytable
WHERE Code = 'TPLM' AND 
      (Thickness >= @myval OR Thickness = (SELECT MAX(Thickness)
                                         FROM mytable
                                         WHERE Code = 'TPLM'))
ORDER BY Thickness
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58aa24/10)

Comment: Why exceeding rather than greater than or equal to?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm just taking a guess. The OP needs to clarify this.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58aa24/7

Comment: Would it be **AND Thickness > = 8.5**?  Otherwise you will miss exact matches.

Comment: If my table thickness maintain in table is until 19.  When I pass in TPLM 30, I need the result is TPLM 19, is it possible?

Comment: @MJH I think the OP has explained that `Thickness` column is of type `int`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos the column is type int.  The value pass in to do a selection can be decimal or int also.  It might be TPLM 8.5, TP 8

Comment: @DerickLoo I see your point now!

Comment: @DerickLoo Please check the edit I made

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Brilliant thanks.  This is what I look for.

Answer (score 1):

> By my understanding,

```
 select * from #code where Thickness > 8.5 and Thickness <= 12 and code ='TPLM'
```

**Solution 2:**

```
declare @thickness int
, @code varchar(max)
set @i = 8.5
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM mytable
WHERE Code = @code AND Thickness > @thickness
ORDER BY Thickness
```